# convert: Wrong JPEG library version: library is 80, caller expects 90 `image.jpg'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, rmagick

I am using Ubuntu 13.04.

I am installing imagemagick. and It is installed properly via source.I find all required delegates.

```
 convert -list configure | grep DELEGATES
```

I get :

```
 DELEGATES      bzlib djvu fontconfig freetype jbig jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr lzma openexr png ps tiff x xml zlib
```

Now, Same code was working in OS `Ubuntu 12.10` before.

Please guide how to solve issue

`convert: Wrong JPEG library version: library is 80, caller expects 90`image.jpg' `

Comment: I got exactly the same problem, just edit your post if it's solved...

Comment: @AlexPierstoval Uninstall and re-install using http://nishant610.blogspot.in/2011/12/imagemagick-installation-with-pnglib.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it didn't work. I removed ImageMagick and installed GraphicsMagick, a compatibility alias for ImageMagick : http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=graphicsmagick

Comment: I'm on windows. I had both ImageMagick and GraphicsMagick and having same error on jpeg conversion. Removing GraphicsMagick did the trick and IM now works perfeclty.

Comment: Thanks for the Hint @Mohsen